# Hostname in configfile of nginx unkown?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am deploying my flask app on a Linode Ubuntu server. I use the Flask series playlist of Corey Schafer on YouTube. But i get stuck on the part where i have to set on the nginx configuration file to get nginx work together with gunicorn. My configuration file is located at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask` and the configuration is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        hostname ashkan-tools.de;

        location /static {
                alias /home/admin/flask/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

ashkan-tools.de is the domain which i already connected with the Linode nameserver and set up the rDNS. I already tried [www.ashkan-tools.de](http://www.ashkan-tools.de) or even the IP of the Linode server. I got this error code from the nginx.conf file using `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "hostname" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

and every time i try to restart the nginx service using `sudo service nginx restart` i get this error code:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I even tried to look at all apps using the port 80 with `sudo lsof -i:80` but the command dont show me anything.

Comment: where did you see `hostname` directive? is it in nginx documentation?

Comment: change it to `server_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx doesn't have `hostname` directive!! change it to `server_name`

[nginx document for server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)